# Django Query to get count of all distinct values for column of mongodb ArrayField

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

What is the best way to count all distinct values in mongodb ArrayField?
Here is my model:

```
class tweet(models.Model):              
   topic = models.JSONField()
```

3 sample documents:

```
1. ["investment", "economy"]
2. ["investment"]
3. ["economy", "politics"]
```

Desire result:

```
[{"investment":2},{"economy":2},{"politics":1}]
```

Maybe something like this:

```
tweet.objects.annotate(t=Func(F('topic'), function='$unwind')).values_list('t').annotate(c=Count('_id'))
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/) instead of djongo or nonrel engine, like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import json_util
import json


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def get_topic(request):


client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['DB_name']
pymongo_tweet = db.appname_tweet

req_query = [
            {
                '$unwind': '$topic'
            }, {
                '$group': {
                    '_id': '$topic', 
                    'count': {
                        '$sum': 1
                    }
                }
            }, {
                '$sort': {
                    'count': -1
                }
            }
            ]

cursor = pymongo_tweet.aggregate(req_query)
cursor_list = list(cursor)


return Response(cursor_list)
```